# Publish MAUI android with keystore and distributing to appcenter via github actions doesnt really sign the apk?

Tags: c#, android, maui, keystore, appcenter

I wanted create a signed android apk, and i  used this guid https://www.koskila.net/how-to-build-a-functional-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-maui-app-from-on-github-in-less-than-1-hour/
all my github action code is the same and after publishing app and distributing to appcenter, when i install app from appcenter on android every time Google Play Protect says that app could contain unsafe, e.g. unsafe, from untrusted source.

So steps i tooke to creat build:

1. created keystore locally on windows machine in cl:

   keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias my_alies -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
2. modified csproj:

   ```
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>my_app.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>my_app_alies</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass></AndroidSigningStorePass>
   ```
3. run command:

   dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=mypassword /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=mypassword
4. got file: myapp-signed.apk

> then decided to use github action to delivery builds

5. set up ci/cd from github action to deploy to appcenter and ran action
6. got build on appcenter
7. distirbuted build from appcenter to myself
8. installing app
9. here every time i install apk play store protect says its untrusted

How could make it trusted?

Comment: The signing key comes from a certificate that need to be trusted.  See : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79041?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng, isnt keystore itself for that?

Comment: No.  The key store just take the key from the certificate, not make the certificate trusted.

Comment: @jdweng, so probably it ends up adding network-security-config xml data?

Comment: Did you read the link?  The config file needs modifications : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>  
      <base-config>  
            <trust-anchors>  
                <certificates src="system" />  
                <certificates src="user" />  
           </trust-anchors>  
      </base-config>  
 </network-security-config>

Comment: @jdweng, yes, thanks, just wondering this issue...